# Java/Kotlin run Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with visible command prompt

Tags: java, kotlin, runtime.exec

On my windows system, I would like to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` to launch a subprocess with a python script and have the command prompt terminal open so users can see the process working. My command is something like:

`val command = "cmd /c python ~path_to_file~ ~args~"`

I'm aware there's an alternate method to print the contents of the command prompt back into the original terminal via something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C dir") 
    Scanner(proc.inputStream).use {
        while (it.hasNextLine()) println(it.nextLine())
    }
}
```

Just wondering if there's another option I haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use `ProcessBuilder`'s redirecting:

```
fun main() {
    ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "dir")
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
        .start()
        .waitFor()
}
```

This example has same behavior as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can replicate the same behaviour as above but there's no visible command prompt/terminal that appears to display the output. I'm fine with re-directing, but is there a way I can force open the terminal?

Comment: @PeptideWitch yes. Try replacing `cmd /C dir` with `cmd /C start dir`

Comment: this worked for me, windows 10
```kotlin
ProcessBuilder("cmd /C start dir".split(" "))
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
        .start()
        .waitFor()
```